# Soft Keyboard next press not moving to the edittext below it but moves rightwards

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an layout in which have multiple editTexts. I want that when next of soft keyboard's is pressed the focus should move to the edittext below the edittext which previously had focus. But when next is pressed, the focus moves to the edittext which is placed to the right of the edittext which previously had focus. I found that it moves down if I remove the onEditorAction Listener from the edittext. But the problem is that I have some functionality which is dependent on onEditorAction Listener and hence can not remove the onEditorAction Listener. So please provide some solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually set where focus should move:

```
EditText et2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et2);
EditText et3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et3);

// Set keyboard next buttons
et1.setNextFocusDownId(R.id.et2);
```

But you have to be careful about setting android:nextFocusDown in your XML layout because errors will be thrown if the objects you are referencing haven't been created yet. 
[Info from here](http://androidadvice.blogspot.fi/2010/10/soft-keyboard-next-button-not-working.html)